# Print connection password typed by user on NodeMCU Lua ESP8266 ESP-12E

Tags: esp8266, wifi, nodemcu

I want to make a WiFi Access point created with the ESP8266. Let's say that the SSID is '**net_work**' and the password is '**12345678**'.

When a client tries to connect with a **wrong** password, I want to print that wrong password in the serial console. But nowhere in the docu I can find an event listener or something to do this... The only thing i can find in the docu is how to start the AP and wait for a successfull connection.

Comment: You can't print the password because you never know the password. The AP is never sent the password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.

The password does not exist.

In short:

- The password is used to create a key
- The key is used to encrypt the connection
- If both ends agree on the encryption then it's "connected" and packets can travel back and forth.

There is no password for you to print, only the fact that encryption didn't agree.

It actuality it's more complex than that, but that's the rough outline of how it works.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe a question that does not belong in this topic, but do you know a book or a search term where to learn such deeper understanding about networks, connections and protocols?

Comment: https://www.ietf.org/standards/rfcs/